# how to add individual column search in datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

hi this is my server side data table. I want to add individual column search option. when i want to search then the all search needs to filter with my search input.
here is my code.

the php code named with fetch.php connected with the database and its retrive the data from database.

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sbcldb_management", "sbcldb_management", "management_server2021");



$column = array('order_customer_name', 'order_item', 'order_date', 'order_value');

$query = '
SELECT * FROM tbl_order 
WHERE order_customer_name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_item LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_value LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 

';

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY order_id DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();

$total_order = 0;

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row["order_customer_name"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["order_item"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["order_date"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["order_value"];

 $total_order = $total_order + floatval($row["order_value"]);
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_order";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 'draw'    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 'recordsTotal'  => count_all_data($connect),
 'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
 'data'    => $data,
 'total'    => number_format($total_order, 2)
);

echo json_encode($output);


?>
```

Here is the javascript code that calculate the subtotal. it shoul work with the individual search option.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#order_data tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
  
   var dataTable = $('#order_data').DataTable({

    
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetch.php",
     type:"POST"
    },
    drawCallback:function(settings)
    {
     $('#total_order').html(settings.json.total);
    }
    
    
   });

    
  
 });
 
</script>
```

and this one is just a simple html formate.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>How to Get SUM with Datatable Server-side-processing in PHP</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container box">
   <h3 align="center">How to Get SUM with Datatable Server-side-processing in PHP</h3>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="order_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Customer Name</th>
       <th>Order Item</th>
       <th>Order Date</th>
       <th>Order Value</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
     <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <th colspan="3">Total</th>
       <th id="total_order"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                
            </tr>
     </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

please help me doing this.

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: the individual search is not working. how to search as individual column

Comment: I see no individual search in your query. Is this `"%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_item LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR order_value LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"` where you're trying to do that?

Comment: Or you mean the individual search in the footer?

Comment: i did not added the code as i dont know how to do that. please help me with this